# Floats and scientific notation

Tags: c++

I am creating 1D and 2D array from a file that contains lines that look like this:

42857000 -923070    0        0      -7887
428570   -546190    -4285700 546190  0
-6.5     -0.15384   6.5      0.15384 0.007
0         0         42857000 360570  0

When I populate the arrays from the file, they get converted to scientific notation:

42857000 >>>>>  4.2857000e+007   etc!!!

Is there anyway to stop this?

My arrays are defined as follows:

```
float aMatrix[DEFROWS][DEFCOLS] = {0.0};
float bMatrix[DEFCOLS] = {0.0};
```

This issue is causing my app to crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is just from printing with `cout`. If that's the case, use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
std::cout << std::fixed << whateverNumberCurrentlyInScientific;
```

Comment: ok thanks that worked but is there any special consideration when reading in signed numbers? It still crashes. The same code runs fine with integer numbers.

Comment: @MichealNoel, No need for the link; lots of people, most likely including myself, will see it when it comes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it crashing on reading it in or sending it out? Are you using cout or printf? One extremely common way to crash it to use printf with a %d and send it a floating point value.